# GROUP BY using Perl

Tags: sql, perl, group-by

I have a ton of SQL logs that I want to extract data from. This task takes a very long time because I am grouping by several columns. Thus, I decided to extract the logs along with the columns I would typically group on without doing a GROUP BY on the SQL side. Instead I want use Perl to do my grouping by. When using Perl, the solution I'm thinking of is to create an n-dimensional hash to group by on the different columns. Are there any command line utilities or Perl functions that will allow me to do the same?

Comment: It's probably not going to be any faster than letting your database do the grouping.  You should look into optimizing that query, instead.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what led you to believe that you are having a problem with group by?

Answer (score 2):

1. As Ether said in the comment, let the tool that was actually engineered and optimized for the job do the job. A database server running properly optimized query is VERY unlikely to be any slower than you yourself can achieve outside of DB.

   Among other things, you will waste resources on transmitting more data over the network and will need more memory.

   As one of optimizations, try to use a temp table, though without having full schema and query and DB engine I wouldn't venture into giving any specific optimization advice.

   The outside-of DB approach could sometimes be better, for example if there are VERY VERY few rows that have duplicate "grouped by" keys, in which case there's pretty much no savings in terms of resources to transmit the grouped data; AND when your logic on the Perl side would have necessitated storing every row in memory anyway instead of iterating over them and throwing iterated ones away.
2. If you still want to try to do this in Perl, a good approach is to do a SINGLE level hash, and develop a cheap way to encode the values in your unique key columns into a single hash value (pack/unpack can be used in some circumstances, or split/join, or more situation specific but better performing ways). The only requirement is that the encoded value can be uniquely mapped back to the unique key column values.

   ```
   # Store
   my %storage;
   foreach my $row (@$result_set) {
       my $hash_key = encode_hash_key(row);
       my $new_row = $row;
       if (exists $storage{$hash_key}) {
           $new_row = merge_rows($row, $storage{$hash_key});
       }
       $storage{$hash_key} = $new_row;
   }
   ```

Comment: A good, cheap way is to use perl's old multidimensional array emulation (see perldoc -v "$;"), so something like this:  $storage{ $row->{field1}, $row->{field2}, $row->{field3} } = merge_row( $storage{ row->{field1}, $row->{field2}, $row->{field3} }, $row );

Comment: or make encode_hash_key simply join($;, @$row{ @group_by_fields })

Comment: @MKV - the downside of joining the keys as encoding is the cost of decoding via split, as well as attendant complexities when the values can contain commas. It CAN be one of the methods, but in some (or many) situations not the best performing one if you care about decoding.